# How to get user input in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, web, user-input

How do I get user input in JavaScript? Because I am making a website where you input your email and then it puts the input in to a text file.

Here is my code:

```
<button type="button" onclick="var_Name()">Enter email</button>
<script> 
    function var_Name() {
        email_1 = prompt("Please enter email. Thank you.");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Not quite what you want, maybe, but see http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Comment: You already are capturing the input. Is the question you are asking how to save that to a text file?

Comment: Yes I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

do you have a popup message box ?! my suggest is [Magnific Popup jQuery Plugin](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/)

in another way you wanna write your code for this popup message form just write a div with display [style] none and in your js set display inherit
 But remember Position Mostly is Absolute and have black with opacity 0.6 background for fill your webdesign.